# git pull/fetch - fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git, bash

While using the below `git pull/fetch` command, getting fetal error.

```
$ git pull origin <branch_name>
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I am using `git bash` interface to run the command in windows 7. All other commands like `git status, commit and push` etc. are working fine. I have changed the git server password, so it should asked the new password, but it is giving the above error message.

**Note:** I searched this issue on stack-overflow, but solution about this problem could not be found.

Comment: [Did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240815/git-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly) [you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269922/permission-denied-publickey-when-deploying-heroku-code-fatal-the-remote-end) [try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608801/git-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly) [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446632/git-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly)?

Comment: I don't want to use ssh, but want to use https

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I restarted my machine(Windows) and then `git pull/fetch` command started working.

So I could not find the exact problem, but I solve the issue as above.